# How to Load an Image onto PictureBox in Visual Studio using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, picturebox

I have been trying to use the following code to Load an Image from My Resources to A picture Box on **Visual Studio 2012 using C#.**

```
pictureBox1.Load(Properties.Resources.Desert);
```

And I have been getting the following errors.

1. The best overloaded method match for `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Load(string)` has some invalid arguments
2. Argument 1: cannot convert from `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to `string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Load` method takes a `string`. You are directly passing it a resource which is a `Bitmap`.. this won't work.

Try this:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Desert;
```

This will directly set the image in the `PictureBox` to be the `Bitmap` in your resources.

Comment: Thanks It works !! 
Also, I have around 50 Images named M1,M2.... M5 in my Resources.

How can I use a variable to pin point these images

    PictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.Variable;